# Easy way to store metadata about SQLite Database

Tags: database, sqlite, metadata

I was wondering if there is a simple way to store meta information about an sqlite-Database in that database.

I am specifically thinking about a version number that lets you easily find out which version of a database layout you are using (So my code could check if the database structure is compatible without querying `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';` and comparing the result with a predefined schematic). To clarify: I am *not* interested in the version number of the sqlite software, but something akin to pythons `__version__` variable that can be defined seperately for each python file.

I know that I can probably just create a table named "meta" and save it there, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do that.

I also know that checking compatibility by only checking a version number has some problems, and I will still do other checks if necessary, but for now I am only interested in the version number I described.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to check out the [user_version pragma](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version).

Comment: Right, Pragma. Had to learn too much regular SQL during the last weeks, completely forgot about them. Thanks, will accept as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there something similar for MySQL? `pragma` is a feature of SQLite which is not available in MySQL, as far as I know.

Comment: Note the plain http link is dead, try https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version

Comment: @Siwel: Still worked for me, but I updated to use https anyway like you suggested just in case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

SQLite offers two slots to store an integer as metadata.

**application_id**

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_application_id

Set an application_id to 900

```
PRAGMA application_id = 900;
```

Get the application_id

```
PRAGMA application_id;
```

**user_version**

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version

Set an user_version to 901

```
PRAGMA user_version = 901;
```

Get the user_version

```
PRAGMA user_version;
```